# Hpw can I fix auto complete with git after a macOS update?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, git, auto-complete

My command line autocomplete isn't working with many third party binaries. This started with a macOS Ventura 13.5 dot update.

I try to tab to operate a previously working autocomplete for git commands, they fail.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly did you update with the last update? Also, how did you install auto-completion (it doesn‘t come with macOS), and did you try to reinstall it?

Comment: You did not describe how you have configured bash to do auto-completion, and you did not describe which autocompletion failed.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, I reinstalled bash completions via Homebrew

```
brew reinstall bash-completion
brew cleanup bash-completion
```

and ensured that it gets loaded from `~/.bash_profile` by adding the following line there.

```bash
[[ -r "$(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && . "$(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
```

Comment: It’s good to self-answer your own question, but please be aware the question and answer both lack certain quality attributes like which OS you’re running (Bash is no longer the default), what happened *exactly* to cause the issue, which auto-completion you installed, etc.  Likewise, your answer lacks sufficient supporting details to explain why doing what you prescribe is the correct solution. .

Comment: I was using OSX as my operating system.
The issue I encountered was related to auto-completion.
The solution I found was to reinstall the auto-completion tool.
I appreciate your feedback, and I'll keep these suggestions in mind for future posts to ensure they are more helpful to others facing similar problems.

Comment: I’m going to assume you’re on Ventura since that would be reasonable for July 24, 2023.